# Hangman Java - Replacing Underscores

Tags: java, replace

I am almost finished my Hangman game, but I have a problem with replacing correctly guessed letters' underscores with those letters. An infinite loop is created whenever I select a correct letter. Any help is greatly appreciated.

//public String phrase;

//public String newMask;

```
public boolean showLetter(String letter)
{
    phrase = phrase.toUpperCase();

    int pos = phrase.indexOf(letter);
    if(pos != -1) { //If the letter is part of the phrase.
        do {
            //Letter and phrase don't change.
            //Cut the "a" 

            pos = phrase.indexOf(letter);
            //Make a new string and take the digit out. 
            //I must break out of the loop.
            //add code here 

            newMask = phrase.substring(0,pos)+phrase.charAt(pos)+phrase.substring(pos);

        } while (pos != -1);
        setValue(mask);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why it will NOT create infinite loop ??? `letter` will be always same inside the loop. Hence `pos` will not get changed. Then how the control will come out from the loop ? Dont understand what is the use of loop?

Comment: The use of the loop is to replace all necessary underscores with correct letters. For example, because letter is "All's well that ends well!", if I pick "e", all of the underscores that represent "e" are changed to e. Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: cant you use String `replace()` method ?

Comment: Take a look at [`String#indexOf(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-int-). You need to start from the last found index + 1, otherwise you're just repeating the same action over and over. Also the line `newMask = ...` currently replaces the whole mask with `phrase` (with one letter doubled), which is probably not what you want.

Comment: why do you need do while loop here ? if you want to loop then do it on the function  `showLetter(String letter)`

Answer (score 0):

Hey tommy i made similar method when u entered the letter it will check if its in the phrase String and if its in it, it will return true, and print out the new mask.

```
static String phrase = "Word";
static String mask = "_ _ _ _";
public  boolean showLetter(String letter)
{       
    phrase = phrase.toUpperCase();
    for(int v  =0; v < phrase.length();v++){
        if(phrase.charAt(v) == letter.toUpperCase().charAt(0)){                
            String newMask = "";
            mask =mask.replace(" ", "");
            for(int vv = 0;vv < mask.length(); vv++){                    
                if(vv == v){
                    newMask = newMask +  letter.charAt(0) + " " ;
                }else if (mask.charAt(vv) != '_'){
                    newMask = newMask +mask.charAt(vv) + " ";
                }else{
                    newMask = newMask + "_ ";
                }
            }
            mask = newMask;
            return true;
        }            
    }
    return false;
}
```

Input : "w"

Output : True , "w _ _ _ "

if you dont want to print out the output put " // " in front of System.out.println(mask);